# How do I transfer multiple selected table view cells data to the next view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

So I have a lot of code already in place for this but I am getting some errors:

My Current code is :

```
func createGroupMessagesButton() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {

        let user = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        self.messagesController2?.showChatLogController(user)
    }
}
```

The code above is meant to dismiss the current view controller, and pass all of the data into a function on the next view. That functions code is:

```
func showChatLogController(user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    chatLogController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)

}
```

The function above then pushes to another controller with that data that was passed down to the function above.

The only problem is that when I first try to pass the data I get an error that states:

Cannot convert value of type [NSIndexPath]? to expected type argument User

[image: This is a picture of the error]

PS: User is an array that I have created.

This is my user array:

class User: NSObject {

```
var id: String!
var fullName: String!
var email: String!
var userPhoto: String!
var homeAddress: NSArray!
var schoolOrWorkAddress: String!
```

}

To sum up my issue I am having trouble passing the data of multiple selected table view cells.

If you would like to know how I pass one selected cells data this is how:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing != true {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
            self.messagesController?.showChatLogController(user)
        }
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.fullName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email

    if let userPhoto = user.userPhoto {

        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(userPhoto)

    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `NSIndexPath` is a construct to get a path to a specific row in a specific section.

The `self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns you a list of selected rows, so you'll then have to loop through them and use the `row`-attribute to find the corresponding user in your complete list of users. Also note that you most likely want to pass an `Array` of `User` instead of just one.

This is conceptional code of the top of my head, that should lead you in the correct direction.

```
func createGroupMessagesButton() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {

        let selectedUserRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        var selectedUsers = [User]
        for let selectedUserRow in selectedUserRows {
            selectedUsers.append(self.users[selectedUserRow.row]!)
        }
        self.messagesController2?.showChatLogController(selectedUsers)
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of all users you're displaying, you'll have to change this to fit your application.

Comment: The line `let user = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` means that you want to know what rows are currently are selected, if there aren't any, this line is not needed?

Comment: In that case your question is too broad and missing some necessary information or the code is plain wrong.

Comment: `self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` is returning an Array of `NSIndexPath`. This array contains the information which cells are selected, you then have to use this information to find the users associated with the cells. That's what I've done in my answer

Comment: It's not clear *where* you want to append these *users*. I'd suggest you to update your question and providing more information, I can't help you until then.

Comment: I assume the following: A user is on a screen, sees a list of other users, selects one or more of them, then clicks a button that'll call `createGroupMessagesButton`, the user-list disappears, you want to know the selected users, then pass it to `showChatLogController` that'll show the `ChatLogViewController` with the selected users as recipients. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, my code does the same as your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`-function did except it creates an `Array` of users instead of just one. Is your `showChatLogController` / `ChatLogController` capable of receiving multiple users at once (`[User]`) instead of just one single `User`?

Comment: just single but I dont know why

Comment: Well, if you want to create a group message with multiple users you must be capable of receiving a list of users instead of just one.

Comment: yeah i understand but for some reason it does not work

Comment: should I construct a new array specifically for groupUsers

Comment: I'd suggest to only accept an array of users and if you make a single-user message you just call it with an array of 1 user

Comment: yeah but I am trying to create group messages

Comment: Correct, I'm suggesting improvements in maintainability and code design, because I assume you're beginner level in programming.

Comment: I recommend that `ChatLogViewController` only handles an `Array` of `User`, if you just need a single-recipient-message you pass an `Array` with just one user. That way you can have a arbitrary amount of users passed to the `ChatLogViewController` and this will most likely also solve your current problem.

Comment: Yes but I already have that working. I wanted to make it so that there are multiple message recipients. Hence group messages

Comment: could I maybe create a new array for every group and then store all of those arrays inside one main array?